# Determining the Length of DNA in a Human Spermatozoon

Tags: human-biology, dna, human

**Hello everyone**,

I’m currently trying to solve a problem related to DNA length in human spermatozoa and could use some guidance.

The problem states: “The DNA of one human spermatozoon contains ***10^23*** pairs of nitrogenous bases. Determine the length of the DNA molecule in a human sperm.”

I know that the distance between two base pairs in a DNA molecule is approximately 0.34 nm. So, I’m thinking that I need to multiply the number of base pairs by this distance to get the length of the DNA molecule.

However, I’m not entirely sure if this is correct or if there are other factors I need to consider. Also, I understand that this calculation will give an approximate value and the actual length can vary depending on the specific sequence of the DNA molecule.

Could anyone confirm if my approach is correct or provide guidance on how to accurately calculate this length? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Hi Wino, welcome! Is the question about bp length or actual length? If this is about bp length then I think the answer is in your question. Maybe there is some additional context to the problem?

Comment: This site is not a service for people to check their homework before submitting it. Please desist.

Comment: 10^23 is an absurdly large number. Should be 10^9 ish. Approach seems correct. There is a book Cell Biology by the Numbers which you can use to verify your answer.